# authentication_ui_failed: The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete

Tags: win-universal-app

Using below method query a token result in universal app:
     AcquireTokenAsync(string resource, string clientId, Uri redirectUri,        PromptBehavior promptBehavior);

No problem in F5 debug mode, but hit error when installed the app manually by a published store app package.

the error message:

*authentication_ui_failed: The browser based authentication dialog failed to 
complete. The system cannot locate the resource specified. (Exception
from HRESULT: 0x800C0005)*

Comment: which azure active directory nuget package version you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the capabilities of your universal app. Following capabilities must be enabled for AAD browser authentication UI popup to be shown:

1. Enterprise Authentication
2. Internet(Client & Server)
3. Private Networks(Client & Server)
4. Shared User Certificates

If you want to enable them from the package.appxmanifest xml file of your app you should have following entries inside Capabilities tag as below which corresponds to above capabilities in the same order:

```
<uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication"/>
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
<uap:Capability Name="sharedUserCertificates" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you have a source for why these are required? I'm having a similar issue, where only after the app is signed and published via Windows Intune, *some* users get the authentication_ui_failed error when the app is loaded for the first time.

Comment: All I needed was <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />

Comment: do you know how to correct the same problem on Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: Terrible that the error message is not much more clear. This suggested capabilities are all necessary. But does this also need internetNetworkClientServer because of using mobile internet / 4G

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message, although my problem was that I was using wrong ***redirectURI***.
Need to use the one generated by:

```
redirectURI = Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
```